# ReactiveCocoa 4 progressive collect operator

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa

ReactiveCocoa has a `collect` operator which aggregates all next values into an array until the signal or producer completes then sends that aggregated value. What I need is a progressive collect operator where values will collect into an array until a filter condition is passed at which point the array will be forwarded and the operator will start over again at an empty array and aggregate values all over again.

For example, if given a producer that emits the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 in that order and a `collectWhile` operator:

```
producer.collectWhile { $0 % 5 == 0 }.on(next: { print($0) })
```

there'd be two print statements:

`[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

at which point `self` would complete and so would the `collectWhile` operator.

`collect` is built off of `reduce` but it uses a private data structure:

```
/// A reference type which wraps an array to avoid copying it for performance and
/// memory usage optimization.
private final class CollectState<Value> {
    var values: [Value] = []

    func append(value: Value) -> Self {
        values.append(value)
        return self
    }
}
```

to avoid copying the aggregate values so I assume I'd probably have to do something similar in my implementation. Any one have any thoughts on how I can accomplish the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find how to do it?

Comment: They're implementing it on their Github: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/pull/2835